# Binding all texts in TextBox from a html file - HtmlAgility

Tags: wpf, binding, textbox, listbox, html-agility-pack

I have to make this app to show all texts from a html file, each text in his TextBox. so i did this ti'll now and i don't know how to continue:

.xaml.cs

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.Filter = "HTM | *.htm";

        if (open.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            doc.Load(open.OpenFile());

            var listItems = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//ul").SelectNodes("li");
            var src = new List<string>();
            foreach (var li in listItems)
            {
                src.AddRange(li.Descendants("p").Select(x => x.InnerText));
            }

            myListBox.ItemsSource = src;
        }
```

.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Open" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    <ListBox Name="myListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="249" Margin="10,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="400" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question? What's wrong with your code? This question needs much more information... please read the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page from the Help Center to help you improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I think I see your problem... you're trying to data bind to a property named `Description` in your XAML. Would you like to show me where that property was declared, because I can't see one. Furthermore, your `ListBox.ItemsSource` is set to a `List<string>`, so there can't be any `Description` property to bind to. Instead, try this:

```
<TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="400" Text="{Binding}" />
```

Comment: i didn't declare it because i don't know where and how to declare it.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be writing WPF, or asking questions here. Go off and learn [the basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752299(v=vs.110).aspx) and *then* come back and try again.

Comment: oh, you are so kind :)

I know I shouldn't but I need. I'm now in WPF so i know nothing, and in basics of WPF I didn't find anything about my question

Comment: You wouldn't try to speak English without learning the basics, so why do you think you can write WPF without learning the basics? The link to 'the basics' was to help you understand how WPF works in general - it was not meant to be an answer to this question. From the StackOverflow [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.* You haven't shown that, so you shouldn't be asking questions here.

Comment: `Text="{Binding /}"` binds to the current item from a collection. If this is data bound to a `string` then the current item would be the first character. If you want to see the whole `string` then just use this: `Text="{Binding}"`.

Comment: <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="400" Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>

this works!